# Template function accepting any type similar to map<X, Y>

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way to make something like this work:

```
template<typename T, typename X, typename Y>
void myFunc(T<X,Y> map, X x, Y y) {
    map[x] += y;
}
```

Basically I want anything that acts like a `map<X,Y>` to be valid input.

Is this possible?

I get this error but I don't know what it means:

> test.cpp:2:17: error: ‘T’ is not a template

Comment: Why not just `template<typename X, typename Y> void myFunc(std::map<X,Y> map) { ... }` ?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - Because I want my function to accept `map<X, Y>`, `unordered_map<X,Y>`, `concurrent_hash_map<X,Y>`, etc.

Comment: Perhaps a slightly more semantic approach than my overly broad answer would be to check for the existence of a `key_type` and `mapped_type` member type. That could be done with trait checks. On the other hand, the square-bracket operator is really very special and only exists for very few data structures...

Comment: Aside: you probably want `map` to be passed by reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with template template template arguments:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class M, typename K, typename V>
void Foo(M<K, V> & container)
{
  // ...
};
```

Note that this will never match any real-word container, though, because those have many more template arguments. Better with variadics:

```
template <template <typename, typename, typename...> class M, typename K, typename V, typename ...Args>
void Foo(M<K, V, Args...> & container)
{
  // ...
};
```

If variadics aren't an option, you could leverage a bit of wrapping yourself:

```
template <typename Container> void FooImpl(Container &);

template <template <typename, typename> class M,
          typename K, typename V>
void Foo(M<K,V> & c) { FooImpl(c); }

template <template <typename, typename, typename> class M,
          typename K, typename V, typename A1>
void Foo(M<K,V,A1> & c) { FooImpl(c); }

template <template <typename, typename, typename, typename> class M,
          typename K, typename V, typename A1, typename A2>
void Foo(M<K,V,A1,A2> & c) { FooImpl(c); }

// etc.
```

For reference, `std::unordered_map` takes five template parameters (key, value, hash functor, equality predicate, allocator). Boost's `bimap` might take even more.

Abuse of this last construction could be prevented by making the functions static members of a wrapper class and making the implementation private, and by providing a single free accessor helper function.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use just `T` as argument type.

```
template<typename T, typename X, typename Y>
void myFunc(T map, X x, Y y) {
    map[x] += y;
}
```

Note that this will allow eg. arrays as `T`s (eg. `T = int*, X = int, Y = int` and the function will add `y` to the `x`-th element of array `map`.

If you want to narrow it down to maps, you have to decide what *is* a map according to you. One possibility of recognizing maps would be inspecting for their `key_type` and `mapped_type`. Eg.:

```
template<typename T>
void myFunc(T map, typename T::key_type x, typename T::mapped_type y) {
```

If you really want accept anything that takes two type arguments (and not more), you can use template-template arguments. I, however, think that this is an overly syntactic distinction, and you shouldn't use it unless you plan to instantiate the template-template parameter with multiple argument types.

Comment: Doh. Should've thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't constrain map to be of type T, things become much simpler:

```
template<typename T, typename X, typename Y>
void myFunc(T map, X x, Y y) {
    map[x] += y;
}

// ...

map<int, int> myMap;
myFunc(myMap, 5, 7);
```

std::map actually has more parameters than just K and V (it has a comparator and an allocator as well), so it's probably better to not match it's template arguments. The code above will still only compile for things that have a non-const operator[] taking an X as a key and returning a Y as a value, but it is also flexible for containers that aren't specifically Container, for example, Container.